# Stability of analytic Zariski structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory, open-problems

Noetherian Zariski structures are introduced by Hrushovski and Zilber(1996).
An analytic Zariski structure is a generalization of Noetherian Zariski structures, introduced by Zilber and Peatfield.

For more details you can see the following interesting papers:

1) Zariski Geometries, Zilber and Hrushovski.

2) Analytic Zariski structures and the Hrushovski construction, Peatfield and Zilber.

**Question :** Under what conditions an analytic Zariski structure is stable ?